# Couldn't deploy New function in Firebase cloud or delete the Existing Function

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I Deployed a Basic function using Node js&NPM,

I deployed the below function
[Here is the sample of My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnFoC.png).
Now I'm trying to delete it using by two ways

1)firebase cli delete command.

2)Manually through fire base console by this its getting deleted but it is getting re deployed again once we refresh the console.

I Need to Delete the existing function and Deploy the new one while I used
firebase `functions:delete myFunction` the below error msg is printed in my console.

```
Failed to initialize region (action ID: 1c8a635338f38ddd): Cloud 
   storage operation for gcf-sources-226869492485-us-central1 failed as 
   the billing account is not available
   Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
   profileOnCreate(us-central1)
   i  functions: cleaning up build files...
   !  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could 
   result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to 
   delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually 
   at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/stract- 
   testing/us-central1/gcf-artifacts
```

2. Even I tried to delete it manually using the Firebase console it is getting deleted for a Moment and after refreshing the screen the same deleted function is deploying again with latest time stamp.

Comment: Not sure if this is just a mistype but you have some error in your code (on the screenshot your file isn't saved, and in code you shared there is symbol: ` 

> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions

Comment: Not sure with the saved Part and the '>' symbol is a typo sorry for that, I just tried by saving the code and Deployed again but its still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is the answer to your issue posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68612073/4977439

> Cloud Functions uses another product called Cloud Build to build the server images that actually get deployed. Those images are stored in Cloud Storage, and that storage is billed to your account.

But it could be just a bug, you feel free to contact [Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).